# Showing feature counts for some legend items only in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, legend, feature-count

I would like to display the counts for the year features, but not the National Park boundary or Roads in my legend. I was able to turn the counts on for all of them (Legend Items > show properties > Feature Display Options > Show feature counts), but I don't see any way to make it apply to some items only.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A quick way is to create two legend element, one with only the Year layer and the show feature counts option, the second with the other layers and without feature counts. Set all other setting the same on the two legend element to keep an uniform look